# What to call this intermediate step in my maximum a posteriori calculation?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I have calculated a posterior

$p(P_1, P_2 | D)$

where $P_1$ has a few and $P_2$ has many dimensions. In the process of calculating the [maximum a posteriori estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori) for $(P_1,P_2)$ given certain data $D$, I calculate the maximum projection along all dimensions of $P_2$, i.e.

$f(P_1,D) = \underset{P_2}{max} [p(P_1, P_2 | D)]$

which, given my data $D$, is a function of $P_1$ that I can numerically maximize to find the $P_1$ where the posterior reaches its maximum.

Is this something that is often done? **Does $f$ have a name?**

**Edit:** *Even though I have accepted one answer, Simon in his answer makes a valid point that maximum a posteriori (MAP) in general is a problem, so don't stop reading early ;-)!*

Comment: why would you want to want to do something like this? $f$ need not be a density function necessarily. In strict likelihood terminology, this would be profile posterior distribution.

Comment: @suncoolsu: I realize that $f$ is not a density function, but numerically finding the maximum of the high-dimensional posterior $p(P1,P2|D)$ would be very slow. Since the posterior is "nice" with respect to $P2$, I found an analytical expression for $f$, which allows me to find the MAP much more easily (i.e. less computational burden).

Comment: @suncoolsu, looking at [The profile sampler](http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/abs/10.1198/016214504000001772), [General frequentist properties of the posterior profile distribution](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612191v2) and even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Profile_likelihood), it seems like "profile posterior distribution" is the right answer. Could you turn that part of your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the terminology of [Profile Likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Profile_likelihood) from the maximum likelihood estimation theory, your way of finding the $f$ may be called **profile posterior distribution**.

Answer (score 4):

There is a slight problem with this construction: it doesn't exist. Well, it's not uniquely defined without a further qualification.

The problem stems from the fact that, unlike maximum likelihood estimators, MAP estimators are not invariant under reparameterisation. That is, if we find a MAP estimate $\tilde\theta$ for some parameter $\theta$, and then reparamterise the problem to a different parameter $\psi = \psi(\theta)$, then the MAP estimate for $\psi$ may not be $\psi(\tilde\theta)$.

So, how does this relevant to your problem?

Suppose that your posterior for $(P_1,P_2)$ ends up being a bivariate normal with mean $(0,0)$ and covariance matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, we have:

$$\max_{P_2} \ p(P_1,P_2|D) = p(P_1|D) \max_{P_2} p(P_2|P_1,D)$$

So we just need to find the mode of $P_2 | P_1,D$, which is a normal distribution $N(\rho P_1,1-\rho^2)$, whose mode is the mean $P_2 = \rho P_1$, so your function can be found by simple substitution, giving

$$\max_{P_2} \ p(P_1,P_2|D) = \phi(P_1) p(P_2 =\rho P_1 , P_1|D) = \phi(P_1) \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi (1-\rho^2)}}$$

where $\phi$ is the density of the standard normal.

Okay, now suppose that instead we reparameterise our posterior so that we use $Q_2 = \exp(P_2)$. $Q_2 | P_1, D$ is a lognormal distribution, which has mode $\exp(\rho X_1 - (1-\rho^2))$. So substituting this in:

$$\max_{Q_2} \ p(P_1,Q_2 |D) = \phi(P_1) p(Q_2=\exp(\rho P_1 - (1-\rho^2)) \mid P_1,D) = \phi(P_1) \frac{\exp[(1-\rho^2)/2 - \rho P_1]}{\sqrt{(2 \pi (1-\rho^2)}} $$
which is a different function.

So the lesson is: you have to clarify the variable that you have profiled out.

Comment: +1, I learned a lot from your answer! If I understand you correctly, I have two choices: either justify why my parametrization of $P_2$ is the only sensible one, or ignore my prior and go for a maximum likelihood approach. Is that right?

Comment: Simon, just to be sure: the point you make goes against MAP estimates in general, so it really has nothing to do with taking the profile, right?

Comment: Well, I was merely pointing out that the "profile posterior for $P_1$" was not well defined - that you would need to qualify it "with respect to $P_2$".

Comment: In many cases, there is a "natural" parameterisation: e.g. for logistic regression it makes sense to think in terms of log-odds ratios. Maximum likelihood estimates have their own problems as well (such as when perfect separation occurs). Personally, I would argue that you should marginalise the posterior, not find the mode, but that's a whole different argument (such an estimator may not be parameterisation invariant either, but it wouldn't suffer the problem above).

Comment: Actually in my case I *started* with a marginalization, but the problem is that the result depends very strongly on the exact prior (the likelihood does not go to zero when $P_1\rightarrow\infty, P_2\rightarrow\infty, |P_1|<|P_2|$). To avoid this problem I wanted to use the prior information that "the data *allows* to deduce something about $P_2$"; that seemed to correspond to saying I maximize with respect to $P_2$ instead of integrating it out...?

Comment: I'm missing something.  We don't care about the functions $f$ or $p$: Isn't it correct that we only care about the parameters $P_1$ for which there exists at least one $P_2$ for which the function attains its maximum at $(P_1,P_2)$? As far as I can tell, reparameterization does not change this answer at all; it merely changes our description of the *unique* answer.

Comment: @whuber: I don't quite understand what you're saying. In my examples above, the first function has a unique maximum at $P_1 = 0$, and the second at $P_1 = -\rho$ (if you expand out the terms and match it to a normal density).

Comment: Part of the problem may be the notation, which I haven't been able to completely sort out yet.  I figured out you are using $\phi$ in two different senses, but I haven't yet grasped what $X_1$ is.  But I do get the main point now, which is a good one but becomes somewhat obscured by the context: when continuous distributions can be reparameterized arbitrarily, their modes are not well defined.  (Indeed, by a suitable choice of parameterization you can place the mode *anywhere* within their support.)  Providing that cautionary note is worth an upvote IMO (+1).

Comment: @whuber: Sorry, I think I've fixed the problems now. (the $X_1$ was meant to be $P_1$, and I changed the first $\phi$ to $\psi$.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an official name, but I would call it something like 'the MAP conditional on P1'.

Comment: Thanks for your help - from some googling with your suggestion and the one provided by suncoolsu, it seems that his answer is the right one; I hope I'm not overlooking something here ;-).